# phpMyAdmin - logging client queries?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there a way to find out or to log what kind of queries are being sent by client applications to a phpMyAdmin db?

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

phpmyadmin does offer a brief history. if you click on the 'sql' icon just underneath the 'phpmyadmin' logo, it'll open a new window. in the new window, just click on the 'history' tab.

that'll give you the last twenty or so sql operations.

Comment: Thanks, the history window is blank. So Does it need to be enabled anywhere?